# Place several divs one after another width full width and adjusted width and height for image background

Tags: html, css

I want to show the divs `#botone`, `#bottwo` and `#botthree` one after the other. I also want to have the background image to be adjusted by 100% width and proportional height on `#botone` div.

Now the last two Divs show up behind the `#botone` Div and the `#botone` div adds the 49px to the vertical placement that comes from the `.topnav` Div.

I also want to fixate the `.topnav` Div on top.

```css
** body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 49px;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
}

.blocka {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
}

#botone {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("arc.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#bottwo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#botthree {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="block">
    <a href="#oi">Oi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="blocka">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="botone">testtext
</div>
<div id="bottwo">testtext
</div>
<div id="botthree">testtext
</div>
```

Comment: `#botone` is positioned absolute and the others are not. This means that `#botone` is out of the flow of the document and won't affect the placement of the other 2 divs

Comment: @zgood Thanks. But how can I make the background image to adjust to the full height and width of the window on #botone. height property doesn't seem to work if position is not absolute.

Comment: You could try setting the height to `100vh` if you want it the height of the view-able window (viewport).

Comment: @zgood. Thanks! It worked. Now there's just the topnav div that I want to place fixed on top of the page. position: fixed; doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="block">
      <a href="#oi">Oi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="blocka">
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="botone">testtext
  </div>
  <div id="bottwo">testtext
  </div>
  <div id="botthree">testtext
</div>
```

CSS: (Changes at bottom)

```
body {
margin: 0px 0px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
background-color: #000;
overflow: hidden;
height: 49px;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
float: right;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color:white;
}

.block { float:left;width: 40px; }
.blocka { float:right;width: 250px; }

#botone {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("arc.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
#bottwo {
background-color:blue;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;

}
#botthree {
background-color:yellow;
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
}


/*--- Fixes --*/

.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

#botone {
  /*-- Test --*/
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/948358/pexels-photo-948358.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940");

  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 49px;
  position: relative;
}
```

[link to example](https://codepen.io/RadicalCaitlin/pen/mxxxvb)

Answer (score 0):

A little confused with your requirements description but I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
.topnav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 49px;
  position:fixed; //add this
  width:100%; //add this
}

#botone {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 49px; //add this
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("arc.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

To fixate the top nav or header, use `position:fixed`. You would have to define the width as 100% or it automatically takes a `width: auto`.

To ensure the following div shows directly under the fixed element, give it a margin-top corresponding to the height of the fixed element. If you are using SCSS, this would be much better in responsive design, since you can create a function that applies the height to the margin-top at the same time. But if you are using CSS, just check your @media queries to make sure the height and the margin-top are consistent.

At the moment the blue element is your element that follows the fixed element. If you want to add something in between the blue element and the header (i.e. a slideshow, or banner) treat is as the blue element is being treated now. Give this the margin-top and remove it from the blue element, since the blue element is no longer directly under the fixed header.

See [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWWWvQ)

Or the whole code in the snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 49px;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
}

.blocka {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
}

#botone {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 49px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("arc.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#bottwo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#botthree {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="block">
    <a href="#oi">Oi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="blocka">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="botone">testtext
</div>
<div id="bottwo">testtext
</div>
<div id="botthree">testtext
</div>
```